# Проблема с кнопками и псевдоклассом 'active'

Tags: html, html5, css3, button

При нажатии на одну кнопку реагируют обе. Как это исправить?

```css
* {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  background: #FFF3EB;
}
header {
  background: #333333;
  color: #ededed;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.5);
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
header > span {
  position: absolute;
}
header > address {
  position: absolute;
}
header > address:first-child {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.header-button {
  background: rgba(63, 63, 63, 1);
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #202020;
  margin-top: 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
}
.header-button > span {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
  height: 28px;
  width: 32px;
}
.header-button:hover {
  background: rgba(73, 73, 73, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header-button:active {
  background: rgba(73, 73, 73, 255);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #202020;
}
.header-button:active > span {
  padding-top: 1px;
  height: 29px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Code</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <address>
   <button class="header-button">
    <span>
     <!--<img align="right" height="32" src="github_logo.png" -->
    </span>
   </button>
   <button class="header-button">
    <span>
     <!--<img align="right" height="32" src="mail_logo.png"> --> 
    </span>
   </button>
  </address>
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.header-button {  
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Пример:

```css
* {
  font-family: "Open Sans";
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html,
body {
  background: #FFF3EB;
}
header {
  background: #333333;
  color: #ededed;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 2px rgba(130, 130, 130, 0.5);
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
}
header > span {
  position: absolute;
}
header > address {
  position: absolute;
}
header > address:first-child {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.header-button {
  background: rgba(63, 63, 63, 1);
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #202020;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #202020;
  margin-top: 2px;
  transition-duration: 0.1s;
  width: 36px;
  height: 36px;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.header-button > span {
  display: block;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(180, 180, 180, 0.5);
  height: 28px;
  width: 32px;
}
.header-button:hover {
  background: rgba(73, 73, 73, 255);
  cursor: pointer;
}
.header-button:active {
  background: rgba(73, 73, 73, 255);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #202020;
}
.header-button:active > span {
  padding-top: 1px;
  height: 29px;
  width: 32px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Code</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <address>
   <button class="header-button">
    <span>
     <!--<img align="right" height="32" src="github_logo.png" -->
    </span>
   </button>
   <button class="header-button">
    <span>
     <!--<img align="right" height="32" src="mail_logo.png"> --> 
    </span>
   </button>
  </address>
    <span>TEXT</span>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```